# Flask-SQLAlchemy update row with request.form

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update a row in a database but it doesn't work. I don't know where I could have made a mistake.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/var/www/demo/demo.py", line 466, in dodajk1
    record.si = request.form['si']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'si'
```

My models.py

```
class CC1(dbu.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cc1'
    id = dbu.Column('id',dbu.Integer, primary_key = True)
    si = dbu.Column('si', dbu.Float)
    snd = dbu.Column('snd', dbu.Float)
    snh = dbu.Column('snh', dbu.Float)
    sno = dbu.Column('sno', dbu.Float)
    so = dbu.Column('so', dbu.Float)
    ss = dbu.Column('ss', dbu.Float)
    xa = dbu.Column('xa', dbu.Float)
    xh = dbu.Column('xh', dbu.Float)
    xi = dbu.Column('xi', dbu.Float)
    xnd = dbu.Column('xnd', dbu.Float)
    xp = dbu.Column('xp', dbu.Float)
    xs = dbu.Column('xs', dbu.Float)

 def __init__(self,si,snd,snh,sno,so,ss,xa,xh,xi,xnd,xp,xs):
                self.si = si
                self.snd = snd
                self.snh = snh
                self.sno = sno
                self.so = so
                self.ss = ss
                self.xa = xa
                self.xh = xh
                self.xi = xi
                self.xnd = xnd
                self.xp = xp
                self.xs = xs
```

And finally view.py:

```
@app.route('/dodajk1', methods=['POST'])
def dodajk1():
        if request.form['przycisk'] == 'Submit':
                record = dbu.session.query(CC1).get(1)
                record.si = request.form['si']
                record.snd = request.form['snd']
                record.snh = request.form['snh']
                record.sno = request.form['sno']
                record.so = request.form['so']
                record.ss = request.form['ss']
                record.xa = request.form['xa']
                record.xh = request.form['xh']
                record.xi = request.form['xi']
                record.xnd = request.form['xnd']
                record.xp = request.form['xp']
                record.xs = request.form['xs']
                dbu.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('k1'))
```

Comment: The error says that `record` is `None`, not the form. There is no record with `1` as its primary key.

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Without understanding your application, no. Are you intentionally only updating one record or are you passing an id in the form? Are you using this form to create new records or just edit?

Comment: I want to only update one record. I have an form when user is giving me a new values but I can't have more than one record in my database. When I was adding a nee record to database it works: @app.route('/dodajk1', methods=['POST'])
def dodajk1():
        if request.form['przycisk'] == 'Zapisz':
                record = CC1(si=request.form['si'], [...],  xs=request.form['xs'])
                dbu.session.add(record)
                dbu.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('k1'))

Comment: I think your mistake here is that you're assuming the record you inserted has a primary key of `1`, which is evidently not the case.

Comment: Yes! Now I checked in database it. Somehow there was record with id = 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to update one record, you don't need to use `get`. Instead of selecting the record with `1` as its primary key, select the first record.

```
dbu.session.query(CC1).first()
```

Since you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can shorten this to

```
CC1.query.first()
```